# Binding to Usercontrol Datacontext instead of SelectedItems datacontext

Tags: c#, wpf, datacontext

I have a listbox, where a grid with textboxes shows the listboxs currently selecteditems data. (Code below)

The problem is that i want a delete button inside this grid, however the command it uses lies in the Usercontrols DataContext. How do I make the button recieve the command binding inside the UserControls Datacontext?

Following code lies inside a grid where the visual trees root is a UserControl.

```
        <ListBox Name="list" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource listTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding listCollection, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        </ListBox>

        <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=list, Path=SelectedItem}" Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Margin="7">Name:</TextBlock>
        <TextBox Margin="5" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"></TextBox>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Command="{Binding DeleteSelectedItemCommand}">Delete Selected Item</Button>
        </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick was to wire up the DataContext using Stians reference.

```
<Button 
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType {x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext}" 
Command="{Binding Path=DeleteSelectedItemCommand}">
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean you want to fire the button's command on your UserControls DataContext IE your vm?
Then you need this binding;

```
<Button Grid.Row="1" Command="{Binding Path=DeleteSelectedItemCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type YourControl}}}">Delete Selected Item</Button>
```

Basicly this just traverse up your xaml tree and fetch datacontext from the control called YourControl. You could set UserControl here. The cool thing about this kind of binding is that you may track back the datacontext of any items up the chain :)

[This document is still very handy for bindings that are a bit tricky :)](http://www.nbdtech.com/Free/WpfBinding.pdf)

Cheers,

Stian

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the handy link! Got to love it, however, I do not manage to get it working, I tested if my model was valid. And it was, once I removed the whole grids datacontext, and wired it up regularly by Command="{Binding Path=DeleteSelectedItemCommand}" it works, for me this seems like a conondrum. (Why I can get the DC by RelativeSource) Any idea?

Comment: You replaced word YourControl in AncestorType={x:Type YourControl} to your actuall root element like Windows/UserControl, didn't you?

Comment: RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Im using a UserControl so I believe that is the case to do it?

Comment: @ETG87 as long as you don't run into other usercontrol's your fine, so in this case it should be ok. If there were more you would have to use AncestorLevel in your binding. It's an alternative to target the usercontrol you want.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change DataContext, provide same Name for UserControl and then

```
Command="{Binding ElementName=Name, Path=DeleteSelectedItemCommand}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I do not manage to get it working, I tested if my model was valid. And it was, once I removed the whole grids datacontext, and wired it up regularly by Command="{Binding Path=DeleteSelectedItemCommand}" it works. Mind showing an example?

Comment: Check what is your UserControl DataContext.